# Bulk insert SQL Server 2012

Tags: insert, sql-server-2012, bulk

Trying to use bulk insert to load `.txt` file into SQL Server 2012 database.

```
bulk insert calendar from 'c:\Users\Desktop\textfiles'
with (
    firstrow=1,
    fieldterminator='|'
)
```

I get error

> Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot bulk load because the file "c:\Users\Desktop\textfiles" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).

Googled. Did not find answer.Please give me direction. Thanks!

Comment: Well, the message is pretty clear - the file is not found. Are you running SQL Server on a remote server? If so: the file **must be** on that **remote machine** - not on your own local `C:\users\desktop` ....

Comment: I run SQL Server on my laptop and I put the textfiles on my desktop. Donot why I can not use "bulk insert".

Comment: I put:                                                            bulk insert test3.dbo.campaign from 'c:\Users\Desktop\campaign.txt'
with (
  firstrow=2
  )

Comment: got error:                                                               Msg 4861, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Cannot bulk load because the file "c:\Users\Desktop\campaign.txt" could not be opened. Operating system error code 3(The system cannot find the

Comment: Have you tried to copy the file to another directory? E.g. to `C:\tmp`